# In OpenLayers, how to set feature.style when using attribute-dependent symbolizers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using dynamic (attribute-dependent) symbolizers on a vector layer. In [this CodePen example](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/LVdpXo), we have the colors of the states depeding on the `PERSONS` attribute, which given the number of inhabitants of that state.

I use the `context` property when initializing the Style, I use a StyleMap and everything works just fine.

```
/* Symbolizer */
symbolizer = {
    fillColor: '${getFillColor}',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    graphicName: 'circle'
};

/* Rule */
var rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
    filter: filter,
    symbolizer: symbolizer
});

/* Context */
var context = {
    getFillColor: function(feature) {
        var persons = feature.attributes.PERSONS;
        return convertNumberToColor({
            value: persons,
            min: 453588,
            max: 29760021,
            colorRange: 'gr'
        });
    }
};

/* Style */
var style = new OpenLayers.Style({}, {
    context: context
});
style.addRules([rule]);

/* Style map */
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style);
vector.styleMap = styleMap;
```

The problem comes when I try to highlight one of the features. By highlighting I mean this: maintain all the symbolizers of the feature and only change some. For example, in a red polygon, the highlighting would mantain its red color, but wuld change the strokeWidth.

```
var highlight = function(feature) {
    feature.style = $.extend({}, symbolizer, {
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
    vector.drawFeature(feature);
};
```

As you can see, I want to perform the highlighting in the `feature.style` property, because it does not interfere with the original styleMap and so I can easily remove the highlighting.

Please check out the CodePen above. When highlighting California, the fillColor should remain red, but it changes to green. The same happens with Texas.

Would you please help me to correctly implement highlighting in the `feature.style` propert when using attribute-dependent symbolizers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I found the solution [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Feature-style-doesn-t-support-contexts-td3896881.html).

The `feature.style` property only accepts the symbolizer as hash style. So, we must use the `styleMap` to create a symbolizer for the current feature

```
var highlight = function(feature) {
    var style = $.extend({}, styleMap.createSymbolizer(feature), {
        strokeWidth: 5
    });
    feature.style = style;
    vector.drawFeature(feature);
};
```

I created a [new CodePen](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/zGWreG), where the highlighting works correctly. :)

Answer (score 1):

One other option would be to define a new Style and assign the stroke width...
but the solution you found looks smarter ;)

```
var highlight = function(feature) {
 feature.style = new OpenLayers.Style();
feature.style.strokeWidth = 3;
feature.style.fillColor=context.getFillColor(feature);
vector.drawFeature(feature);
};
```

working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doeMEm

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is nice too. I prefer mine because there may be many dynamic properties. So, the createSymbolizer mthod is really useful. :)